# Swift 3 compatibility version not working with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, communication

I have below code working perfectly fine with Swift 2.2:

```
import Alamofire

struct Communication {

    static let foneKey = "fone"
    static let emailKey = "email"
    static let countryKey = "country"

    enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
        case Init(String, String, String)

        var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {

            let result: (path: String, method: Alamofire.Method, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {

                switch self {
                case .Init(let fone, let email, let country):
                    let params = [foneKey: fone, emailKey: email, countryKey: country]
                    return ("Init", .POST, params)
                }
            }()

            let URL = NSURL(string: baseURLString)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(result.path))
            let encoding = ParameterEncoding.JSON
            request.HTTPMethod = result.method.rawValue
            request.URLRequest.HTTPMethod = result.method.rawValue

            return encoding.encode(request, parameters: result.parameters).0
        }
    }
}
```

But when I made above code Swift 3.0 compatible, then it is not working as expected. Below is the Swift 3.0 code where I get a crash at line `let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL!.appendingPathComponent(result.path))`

```
import Alamofire

struct Communication {

    static let foneKey = "fone"
    static let emailKey = "email"
    static let countryKey = "country"

    enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
        /// Returns a URL request or throws if an `Error` was encountered.
        ///
        /// - throws: An `Error` if the underlying `URLRequest` is `nil`.
        ///
        /// - returns: A URL request.
        public func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
            return URLRequest
        }

        case init(String, String, String)

        var URLRequest: URLRequest {

            let result: (path: String, method: Alamofire.HTTPMethod, parameters: [String: AnyObject]) = {

                switch self {
                case .init(let foneKey, let email, let country):
                    let params = [foneKey: fone, emailKey: email, countryKey: country]
                    return ("Init", .post, params as [String : AnyObject])
                }
            }()

            let URL = Foundation.URL(string: baseURLString)
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL!.appendingPathComponent(result.path))
            let encoding = URLEncoding.methodDependent
            request.httpMethod = result.method.rawValue
//            request.URLRequest.HTTPMethod = result.method.rawValue

            var request1: URLRequest?
            do {
                request1 = try encoding.encode(self, with: result.parameters)
            } catch {
                print("error in URLRequest encoding...")
            }
                return request1!
//            return encoding.encode(request, parameters: result.parameters).0
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the image of crash:
[image]

**Reason of the crash is an Infinite Loop at the above said line.**

I guess there is some issue with Request object creation, but not sure what I am missing. I tried few of the alternatives than above code but none of them worked.

For more information, below is the method calling way for me:

```
func communicate() {
        Alamofire.request(Communication.Router.init("8765432453", "xyz@abc.com", "1").URLRequest as URLRequestConvertible).responseJSON(options: [JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments, JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers]) { (response) -> Void in
            switch response.result {
            case .success:
                if let value = response.result.value {
                    // code handled
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the possible solutions to above problem? One solution that is working is creating Request separately works for me. But I want to have above generic solution which is currently implemented in my application with Swift 2.2.

Comment: Probably your url is invalid; conditionally unwrap rather than force unwrap to see what it is unhappy about.

Comment: @Paulw11: I guess that is not a problem because even though URL is valid or not, Request object creation should not get crash.

Comment: Well, you have an optional `URL` and then you force unwrap it and get a crash, so that would point to `URL` being nil. What is `baseURLString`?  Set a breakpoint and step though checking `URL` for nil

Comment: ok. so my base url is something like this `var baseURLString = "https://xyz.abc.com/mobile/"` It is hardcoded in app.

Comment: What is the exception message?  What does the debugger show for `URL`?

Comment: @Paulw11: Updated answer with the error image. This is because while creating `NSMutableURLRequest ` it goes into infinite loop.

Comment: Have you single stepped through to see why/where it is looping?

Comment: @Paulw11: It is because same class is being initiated while NSMutableURLRequest object is create. Not sure why it is happening. I trying to figure that since long.  Also, I found that in Swift 3, I have to write `asURLRequest ` function. And this function is called everytime when NSMutableURL request object is created. It has to do something with this function but not sure what??... Puzzled with that... :(

Comment: Your variable should not start with a upper case letter; change `URLRequest` to `urlRequest`

Comment: Also change `URL` to `url`